# Why is my text wrapping onto a second line?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get my text properly aligned. However, it's not expanding when there's a long caption or description. Below is what I have..

Screenshot: 
[image]

"The Forum" is fine, but "Subscribe Today!" isn't staying on one line like "The Forum." It happens when there's long text. Also, same thing for the description.

HTML:

```
<div class="hotcampaign-container">
    <a href="' . $item['url'] . '">
        <div id="campaigns_image">
            <img src="' . $item['image_url'] . '" align="left" alt="' . $item['caption'] . '" />
    </a>    </div>
    <div id="campaigns_caption">' . $item['caption'] . '</div>
    <div id="campaigns_desc">' . $item['desc'] . '</div>
    <div id="campaigns_link">
        <a href="' . $item['url'] . '">
            <div align="right">More Info &raquo;</div>
        </a>
        </p>
    </div>
<br />
</div>
```

Div ID's CSS:

```
#campaigns_image {
    padding: 0px 10px 10px;
}
#campaigns_caption {
    padding: 0px 177px 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#campaigns_desc {
    padding: 0px 177px 0px;
}
#campaigns_link {
    padding: 0px 10px 0px;
}
```

Comment: Add rendered html code

Comment: you should increase width of whatever, if text is breaked to next line

Comment: Please put together a jsFiddle showing the rendered HTML and CSS.

Comment: Sorry to say it so harsh, but your code is a mess..., you're not properly closing your elements: `<a><div><img /></a></div>`, also there's a paragraph closing tag `</p>`, but no opening tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
#campaigns_caption{
    padding: 0px 177px 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
    width:auto;
    min-width:300px;//some px according to te scenario
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `whitespace:nowrap;` for the `class` or `id` of the `<div>` that renders "Subscribe today" text.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the padding right to your css of the `#campgaigns_caption` div:

```
#campaigns_caption {
    padding: 0px 0px 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try  [**white-space: nowrap**](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/whitespace/)

```
#campaigns_caption {
    padding: 0px 177px 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: [Agreed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17720473/html-and-css-fix/17720579#17720579)

Comment: @NathanLee Sorry I didn't load the answers at that time.